# How to generate relationship without ArrayCollection type (with Doctrine)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, relationship, arraycollection

I want generate my entities without the dependency Doctrine\Orm\PersistentCollection.

All fields of my entity are mapped in Entity.orm.xml

I would like change the type of the return relationship (ArrayCollection to simple array)

Team.orm.xml :

```
<doctrine-mapping>
    <entity  name="App\Entity\Team" table="team" repository-class="App\Repository\TeamRepository">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>
        <field name="name" type="string"/>
        <many-to-many field="users" target-entity="User"/>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

My property users (isn't in __construct function):

```
/** @var array<int, User[]> $users */
private array $users;
```

I would be happy to receive any ideas or propositions in order to develop our reflections on this issue. Thanks !

Comment: Basically you can't.  Doctrine needs the collection stuff to do all of it's magic.  I'm guessing you are trying to do some kind of DDD and you don't want your Domain Team entity to be dependent on Doctrine?  But at the same time use Doctrine directly for persistence?  It's a bit of a contradiction.  You can use $users->toArray() to retrieve a PHP array.  But otherwise you pretty much just have to live with it.

Comment: What is the best way to insert records with Doctrine which resolve my problem ?

Comment: At this point it's not clear to me what the problem is.  The ORM works the way it does and if that does not fit your requirements then don't use it.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Just stick to ArrayCollection and if you need array, create function like getUsersArray(): array ,
and return with  $users->toArray() on collection.